# ASP.NET WEBAPI c# gives 404 on DELETE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller which works fine on localhost for all verbs used, but DELETE fails on IIS 7 giving 404. The webserver does not have webdav installed and in desperation I have switched off FTP too :)  I just don't know where else to look.

My controller:

```
[HttpDelete]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete()
    {
        oTrace T = new oTrace();


        T.trace("deprovision request");

        string headers = Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString().Split(' ')[1];
        string userpwd = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxxxuserpwd"];

        //try
        //{
        string basicData = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(headers));


        if (basicData != userpwd)
        {

            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
        }
        else
        {


            string[] paths = Request.RequestUri.ToString().Split('/');

            Guid Unique = new Guid(paths[paths.Length - 1]);

            //HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
            //string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            //oProvision myProvision = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<oProvision>(jsonContent);


            //string JSONresponse = @"{""id"":""1"", ""config"": { ""xxON_UNIQUE"":""" + Convert.ToString(Unique) + @"""} }";
            var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            //response.Content = new StringContent(JSONresponse, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            ////kick off GetAppInfoRequest

            BackgroundWorker barInvoker = new BackgroundWorker();
            barInvoker.DoWork += delegate
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                deProvisionAddon(Unique);
            };
            barInvoker.RunWorkerAsync();
            return response;

        }

    }
```

My web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

my webapi.config

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "heroku/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DeleteApi",
            routeTemplate: "heroku/{controller}/Delete/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
```

any help gratefully received as I have been battling this for days.

Comment: How are you calling delete action? If works on localhost and not on iis that may indicates a difference on url

Comment: just changing http://localhost:port/heroku/resources/9400f088-adfc-437f-a229-dfb106dc8db1  to https://domain/FoDHerokuTest/heroku/resources    The GET command works fine on the server

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a route with 'Delete' in the routeTemplate. WebApi knows which action to call based on the HTTP verb you use. So, if you make an HTTP DELETE request **and** your controller action is named "Delete", then it knows, by convention, to call it - no need to specify it by name like you have to with MVC controllers.

Comment: This is a section that I added in desperation...removing it now to see if it helps

Comment: Are you sure you are sending an HTTP DELETE request?

Comment: I can debug the api as the delete request comes through on localhost

Comment: On the server, the request (using jQuery) should look like this: `$.ajax({ url: '/FoDHerokuTest/heroku/resources', type: 'DELETE' });`. Are you sure the **url** is correct in your call on the server?

Answer (score -4):

if you use [HttpDelete]  define the  method ,you should be using delete call webapi ,just like post or get .